# How to refresh a PHP page and show changes after receiving post from jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a client side jquery code which gets the local date of the client and post it to the server. When that post is received on the server side, In my PHP code, I want to make some updates to the page (using echo statements) and show it with those changes. So, how can I force those echo statements to update the page there.

```
<?php 
.....
echo '<span style="color:yellow">Here it does echo fine!</span>';
if(isset($_POST["dateStr"]) && strlen(trim($_POST["dateStr"])) > 0)
{
   echo '<span style="color:red">This doesn't show. What can I do to make it show?</span>';
}
.....
?>
```

The reason I am doing this is to communicate information from PHP to javascript. By echoing, I was expecting to write something to the HTML document, so that javascript could extract information from that updated HTML document. But since this is unlikely to work, what are other ways of sending information from within that if statement of PHP to Javascript?

Comment: You don't you'll have to add that span with jQuery

Comment: I want to make those changes from the server side. I know I can do it from ajax/jquery on the client side. But for some reason, I want to update the page from the server side. Is that even possible?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: you need to reload the page to show the changes, but once you reload the page the original data will be preserved, unless you save the changes to session or cookie. Then on each page load you check if the session variable or cookie exists and if so you load the data from session or cookie, otherwise load the original data.

Comment: @SimoEndre: Basically, I was doing this as a way to communicate from php to javascript. I wanted to echo something to the html document, so that javascript could later read it directly from the html document. But since this wouldn't work, what are other ways to send from php to javascript. And I want to send it from inside that if statement in my code.

Comment: @pythonic use the de facto way: ajax!

Comment: @SimoEndre: I think what you mean is to use jquery get, and have a separate php page which generates json or xml data, which would be parsed by the jquery code. Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by dynamically creating a form and submitting it:

```
$('body')
    .append('<form id="myForm"></form>'); //append a new form element with id myFormto <body>
$('#myForm') 
    .attr("action","#") .attr("method","post") //set the form attributes
    .append('<input type="hidden" name="dateStr" id="dateStr" value="!!YOUR VALUE HERE!!">') //add in all the needed input element
    .submit();
```

Comment: What about using jquery get?

Comment: jQuery.get is a shorthand for the ajax function, it does not refresh the page.

Comment: All I want is some information from the server. I can wrap that information within xml or json through a separate php script, and then parse that infomration with javascript. No?

Comment: Yes, JSON would be advisable. And you can load it with jQuery.get, then. But that's a different question, I tried to answer your initial one.

Comment: Example: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this directly from server side. The reason is that you have to reload the page to show the changes, but once you reload the page the data will not be preserved, unless you save the changes to session or cookie. Then on each page load you check if the session variable or cookie exists and if so you load the data from session or cookie, otherwise load the original data.

The solution is to use Ajax. Here is a simple example with explanations.

**PHP**:

```
if(isset($_POST["dateStr"]) && strlen(trim($_POST["dateStr"])) > 0)
{
   echo "success";
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(function(){
  $('#button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'yourphpcontroller.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {dateStr: 'mystring' }, // can be obtained with jQuery attr
      success: function(data, status) {
        if(data == "success") { // the response coming from php; if the response is success means we can proceed
          $('#myhtmlelement').append('<span style="color:red"></span>'); // append to html tag          
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
  });
```

Comment: This makes no sense if you're not doing anything else with the `dateStr` in PHP. You're just gratuitously doing an AJAX call for no apparent reason.

Comment: Hey, it's only an example. What do you expect? I cannot provide a full working example unless it's not clear requirement.